# DIY copper lamp earthing

Tags: pipe, lamp, copper, uk

I'm planning on building a copper pipe based lamp along the lines of this: https://www.instructables.com/id/Copper-Pipe-Table-Lamp/

I currently have a lamp holder terminal of this brand: https://s-lilley.co.uk/?q=node/147 which has an external earth (like what you can see in [this picture](https://www.lampspares.co.uk/economy-copper-plated-10mm-switched-lampholder-3264257)). It's wired to a standard 3 pin UK plug (all 3 wires are connected).

My question is whether I need additional earthing, or if I need to be particularly careful how I set up and connect the copper piping?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you ...sure... That weird socket is for 230V mains?  It looks like it's for low voltage lighting.  That is a good way to do homebrew lamps because it eases much of the Code requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the earth is connected to the copper pipe and you will be fine. Where exactly the earth is connected on the pipe doesn't matter as long as there is a low resistance path from the earth pin to any exposed metal that houses the live wires.

To make sure it's properly earthed take a multimeter and check continuity between the earth pin on the plug and every exposed copper part.

Comment: Thanks! So if I use a connection like https://www.lampspares.co.uk/22mm-copper-pipe-stop-end-with-10mm-allthread-plu10140/ from the pipe to the holder that should be a low resistance path? I'll verify with a multimeter just to be sure.